# Computation of Automorphism Group

Tags: galois-theory, automorphism-group

Suppose $\theta$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{10}-2$, then determine the Automorphism group of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$.

What I am thinking is $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ automorphism is uniquely determined by image of $\theta$. Any root of $x^{10}-2$ is of the form $2^{\frac{1}{10}}\zeta^k$ where $\zeta$ is $10$th primitive root of unity.

Also since $2^{\frac{1}{10}}\zeta$ is a root, then so is $-2^{\frac{1}{10}}\zeta$ and this is of the form $2^{\frac{1}{10}}\zeta^k$. But I am unable to determine this value of $k$ and would appreciate if someone can guide.

Also how do I show that identity and the conjugation are the only automorphisms?
I think something like $A(2^{\frac{1}{10}}\zeta)=2^{\frac{1}{10}}\zeta^k$ but I cannot conclude anything from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta=\sqrt[10]{2}\in\mathbb R$.

Let $\sigma\colon\mathbb Q(\theta)\to\mathbb Q(\theta)$ be an automorphism, so that $\sigma(\theta)^{10}=\sigma(\theta^{10})=\sigma(2)=2$. Thus, since $\sigma(\theta)\in\mathbb Q(\theta)\subset\mathbb R$, we conclude $\sigma(\theta)=\pm\theta$. Moreover, an automorphism $\sigma$ is uniquely determined by the value of $\sigma(\theta)$.

Thus, the automorphism group has order $2$.

Comment: Here you are using nothing but $\theta$ is a root of $x^{10}-2$ and any automorphism permutes roots. I don't know how it helped you.

Comment: also why did you take $\theta={2}^{0.1}$ when we can have other choices? Basically I am saying that there may exists $p$ such that $p(\theta)$ is also a root of $x^{10}-2$ but you are saying that $p=x$ or $p=-x$, why there are no other polynomials?

Comment: The choice of $\theta$ doesn't matter since any choice gives isomorphic fields. The key point is that there are only two elements $x\in\mathbb Q(\theta)$ with $x^{10}=2$.

Comment: okay, then it is contained in $\mathbb{R}$ or not comes into play. smart!